# How to show two or more editors at the same time?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Eclipse allows to show more than one code editor at the same time... so you can have something like this:

[image]

Can I do something like that using IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: I'm glad to say that issue with spammed editor history is fixed as of 103.190 EAP build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. Click the tab header, then [split vertically/horizontally](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html). (works prior to IDEA 10).
2. Just click the tab header and holding left mouse button move the tab out of the window (separate editor will open). (IDEA 10). (See *Detachable tab editors* section on the [features page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/index.html).)

When using the second option I find that global history (CTRL+ALT+arrows) is spammed. See bug [IDEA-64656 Navigation (Back & Forward) works incorrectly in the case of splitted editors](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-64656) and it is finally fixed in the [103.190 EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+103.190+Release+Notes)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a tab with file name and select 'Split Vertically'/'Split horizontally'
[image: here it is]